# Trying to run fsck manually

Tags: grub, root, fsck

I receive an error and it states that I need to run fsck manually. However, I cannot access the root directly to do this. How can I get to the root directory to get this done? I can get to Grub, but still not able to get to the root directory either.

Comment: You need root privileges to run fsck. The access to the  grub directory is not restriced to root - anyone can acess it but only root can write to it.

Comment: @Cinaed : Understood. I have the necessary user name/password for root access. But how do I navigate to get to root?

Comment: You need to fsck the root filesystem. To determina which filesystem is the root fileystem,  look in /etc/fstab - the one which has the "/" entry is the root filesystem. Or just use "fsck  /" while using a root login. Be extremely careful - you can potentially destroy your system.

Comment: Can I do this while in GRUB or will I need to be in another place?

Comment: Use "cd /" -  it doesn't matter where you are parked. Also, use this command at your own risk - if you get into trouble I can't help you - I don't have the time. As a general rule, don't remove anything even if prompted unless you know what you're doing.

Comment: I am not able to even "cd /" to anything. Any suggestions?

Comment: Try using "fsck /" - you're probably in single user mode anyway.

Comment: Great!! Thank you. I was able to run fsck. Looks like the system will boot now.

Comment: Welcome to the site, and congratulations on finding the solution youself. You may want write it up as [your own answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) so that others facing the same issue can profit from your experience.